# How to get non-overlapped randomly distributed disks using java

Tags: java, random, disk, overlapping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoBoN.png)I built a randomly distributed disks using java but they are overlapping, I would like to avoid this,,
Can anyone help me? I'm a new user of java
thanks

Comment: Is this java or javascript? They're two completely different languages

Comment: I fixed the tag :) @EKW

Comment: Could you add what you tried so far? Without specifics we cannot advice on how to proceed.

Comment: A bit vague question, could you clarify please? Do you need something like Poisson discs (https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/) - points enclosed by some minimal but guaranteed circles?

Comment: I have built disks randomly distributed in a box, but they are overlapping, and I would like that they don't overlap. I know that the idea is that the distance between two disks must be smaller than 2*radius of one disk but the problem is that disks are randomly created, if I will check this condition for 2 disks there will be a third one which will be built and overlap with the previous disk, I hope that I'm clear, If there is a function in java that can do this I will be grateful if someone can help me, @EKW I really don't know the difference :)

Comment: I joined a picture of my geometry

Comment: In your image the cumulative area of the disks seems to exceed the area of the box. Thus there is no way to fit them in without overlap.

Comment: Assuming you mean area overlap and not the vertical difference that would also be possible given your 3D image: You could pick a random location and calculate its distance to all already existing disk centers, and if the lowest distance is greater than zero, you create your disk with that (or a slightly lower) radius and a max radius of X, where X is the largest disk you want to possibly have. If you want to *always use the same* radius, just check if your random spot's min distance is >= that radius. Run the loop a few hundred iterations, and you should be good.

Comment: Sarah, take a look at http://devmag.org.za/2009/05/03/poisson-disk-sampling/, is it what you want?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux it is quite similar,

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux can you tell me if you know how to save the coordinates of an object in java and build others without overlapping?

Comment: I was dealing with java long time ago, cannot help you with code. But here http://code-spot.co.za/2010/04/07/poisson-disk-sampling-example-code/, for example, seems to be reasonable code for java Poisson Disk sampling - grab it, study it and modify as it fits you